# How to get javascript values too with the php simple html dom?

Tags: javascript, php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I am using the **Simple HTML DOM** http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$content = file_get_html('https://www.mesemix.hu/hu/superman-ruhanemuk/11292-szuperhosoek-mintas-zokni.html')->plaintext;

echo $content;
?>
```

The problem is that, the webshop that I am trying to scrape has some javascript in it which contains important values, that I need, like this:

```
var productReference = 'SP- 418070';
```

[This is the webshop's source.](http://view-source:https://www.mesemix.hu/hu/superman-ruhanemuk/11292-szuperhosoek-mintas-zokni.html)

Does anyone has any idea how to get the "SP- 418070" int the plaintext too?

Comment: `preg_match("/var productReference = '(.*?)'/", $content, $m)` -> now it's in `$m[1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing you do is:

Go to their store and press **F12** after that click on **"Elements tab"** you can see all the code in there the selector for the model that you are looking for is :

```
.product_reference .editable
```

if you need to find something just use the ctrl+f for the search menu.

If your code is structured like the demo version on Simple HTML dom

```
$html->find('.product_reference .editable', 0)->innertext;
```

**EDIT**
Use curl , run this code somewhere and you will get the whole web contents

```
<?php
header('content-type:text/plain');
// define the URL to load
$url = 'example.com'; //THE URL THAT YOU NEED
// start cURL
$ch = curl_init(); 
// tell cURL what the URL is
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
// tell cURL that you want the data back from that URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
// run cURL
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
// end the cURL call (this also cleans up memory so it is 
// important)
curl_close($ch);
// display the output
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: No, i need it in my php code. I would like to get the whole site in a plain text, then find the the product ID, and save it in a database, but I don’t know how to get that text which is inside javascript.

Comment: I really need that “SP- 418070” inside the $content plaintext.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am reading this on my phone and I did’t saw the last 4rows of your answer, so sorra for the last 2 comments.

Comment: Check my answer again.

Comment: Can you tell me where I should put this? Im a begginer  $html->find('.product_reference .editable', 0)->innertext;

Comment: make a scrape.php file, upload it to your server and visit the file e.g yoursite.com/scrape.php

Comment: Is there any way to get all of the javascript’s content into the plain text. There are so many, and i don’t want to find them one by one.

Comment: I'm not sure probably but I can't think of a way

Comment: The $html->find('.product_reference .editable', 0)->innertext; is not working for some reasons, but the cURL works fine, thank you so much!